# Vue Js Component Syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I have created a component in Vue JS named "Component". I have learnt that we use the comoponent in a parent component template like this.

```
<template>
   <p>I am a heading </p>
   <Component/>
</template>
```

But if I use the Component syntax like an HTML DOM element syntax and embed more HTML markup inside it, what does it mean actually? I am new to Vue JS and have no idea about this.

```
<template>
   <Component>
      <div> 
       Hello I am a div 
      </div>
  </Component>
</template>
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is about actually. If you just saw this example, and want to understand the use cases, that's covered by [slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) part of Vue doc.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned there are two ways of using Custom components.

We usually use the `self-closing tag` component if we are not passing any child elements

If you need to pass a child to the component you have to use the second method. A child inside a component is called a `slot`

You can read more about slots aka child components in [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) article

Answer (score 1):

The HTML markup inside `Component` tags goes to a slot defined in the component.
So, if `Component` is defined something like below

```
<template>
<h1>This is content of component</h1>
<slot></slot>
</template>
```

and used in parent component as below

```
<template>
  <Component>
    <div> 
      Hello I am a div 
    </div>
  </Component>
</template>
```

then following will actually be rendered

```
<h1>This is content of component</h1>
<div> 
  Hello I am a div 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render that component in the parent component in two ways:

1)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>we are in parent component</p>
    <CustomComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

or
2)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>we are in parent component</p>
    <CustomComponent></CustomComponent>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

now if you need to put custom content inside the child Component, you can do that with vue.js "slot".

this is how it works:

```
// Child component: which is a button that we want to put a custom icon inside it
// componentName: CustomBtn
<template>
  <button class="flex gap-x-2 items-center">
    <span>Click here</span>
    <slot />
  </button>
</template>
```

now inside parent component:

```
<template>
  <CustomBtn>
    <!-- everything inside here, will be passed to the Slot -->
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </CustomBtn>
</template>
```

Vue Js will compile it to this:

```
<button class="flex gap-x-2 items-center">
    <span>Click here</span>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</button>
```